# Drawing pentagonal numbers in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I replicate this image in tikz (in black and white)?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Maybe something like this ?

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.markings} 
\tikzset{corner/.style={
  postaction={decorate},
  decoration={markings,mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 0.2 with {\fill (0,0) circle (2pt);}}
  }
} 
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \size in {1,...,5}{
    \node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=5,draw,anchor=corner 1,rotate=-90,minimum size=\size cm,corner] {};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or more likely, if you really want multiple dots per edge

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.markings} 
\tikzset{corner/.style={
  postaction={decorate},
  decoration={markings,mark=between positions 0 and 1 step {0.2/#1} with {\fill (0,0) circle (2pt);}}
  }
} 
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \size in {1,...,5}{
    \node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=5,draw,anchor=corner 1,rotate=-90,minimum size=\size cm,corner=\size] {};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I was not too sure about the sequence indeed...

Comment: @eulerandeuclid, as this answer seems to cover your needs, would you care to mark it as accepted so that is goes to the aswered questions list ?

Comment: In adapting your code to draw polygonal numbers of other sizes, the main difficulty I encountered was the placement of the dots.  It was only when I realized that you set mark=between positions 0 and 1 step {0.2/#1} since there are five sides to a pentagon that I was able to adjust the spacing of the dots by changing 0.2 to 0.333333333 for triangular numbers, 0.25 for square numbers, and 0.166666667 for hexagonal numbers that I got the placing of the dots correct.  Consequently, I placed my tikzset commands in the document itself so that I could make polygonal numbers of different sizes.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig basically, the code could be improved by parametrizing the style using the number of corners everywhere.