# Figurate numbers in LaTex

Tags: tikz-pgf, number

How can I produce figurate numbers with Tikz, such as the following:

[image]

or the following:

[image]

Are there templates for this kind of representation of number sequences? Thanks in advance!

Comment: My answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/545548/drawing-pentagonal-numbers-in-tikz/545552#545552) may help for the first alternative

Comment: I solved a similar problem in R [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/geom-point-with-2-categorical-variables/83886). When I have time I'll see how feasible it is to translate this to tex.